# @preauthrize or @Secured is not working in Spring Oauth

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

`@Preauthrize` and `@Secured` annotations are not working in *Spring Oauth* (All examples I've referred to are for *Spring* basic security and not for Oauth protocol):

What I've done is:

1. I enabled global security in *spring_security.xml*
2. I used Preauthrize tag in service but it is not working.

Comment: Could you please post what you have done so far, not just bulletpoints but real sources.

Comment: If you provide code we can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)`

To one of your configurations. I have added to my Resource Server Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(2)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("Sample");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //restrict access using @Secured or @PreAuthorize annotation
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Worked flawlessly